# How to check if the program is run from an autostart?

Tags: c++, autostart

Is there any way in C++ to check if my program is launched by a user or from an autostart? I want to show / not to show window in these cases.

Comment: There's probably not a portable way.  You should indicate which OS you're using

Comment: There is no way to "detect" it, but see the answer for a good way to make it work if you have full control over the autostart entry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the autostart entry set a command line flag such as `/nowin`.